# Accents with eulervm and LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, eulervm

I use the euler font for math and compile with LuaLaTeX.
To solve a problem with the accent `\bar`, I load `unicode-math` which resets the mathfont:
[image: standard math font]:

Why does `unicode-math` overwrite `eulervm` and how can I get back to the correct font?

Here is my MWE:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    E &= mc^2\\
    \bar{y}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And what is your problem with the `\bar` accent?

Comment: the euler font is an 8bit font in a traditional weird 7bit TeX encoding, unicode-math resets the entire math typesetting logic to use OpenType math fonts rather than traditional TeX fonts using tfm parameters.  It's possible to mix these things with care for specific symbols, but it can't work to use unicode-math and expect the main font not to be a Unicode font.

Comment: @AboAmmar Try the MWE without `unicode-math`.
@DavidCarlisle Thanks for this information. Would you change the math font via `\setmathfont`? Which one would you load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You surely don't want to load `unicode-math` in order to solve the problem with `\bar` not being defined. Just pass the correct option to `euler-vm`, which cannot cope with `TU` (or `EU2`).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[OT1,euler-digits]{eulervm}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    E &= mc^2\\
    \bar{y}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ,@egreg - Without `unicode-math`, the OP's MWE gives me the same result as yours, I also tried in ShareLaTeX. Am I missing some thing? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AboAmmar I get warnings about unknown encodings and `\bar` undefined