# Accents with eulervm and LuaLaTeX in beamer with sans font

Tags: beamer, luatex, eulervm

This is a follow up to: [Accents with eulervm and LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352723/accents-with-eulervm-and-lualatex)

I am using lualatex with beamer and get and `undefined control sequence` error when using `\dot` or `\ddot`

Specifying the option `OT1` works, but the math font is then serif if used with `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` or I don't get euler font for e.g. the `x` if used without `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
% !BIB program = biber
\documentclass[lualatex, aspectratio=169, 10pt, english]{beamer}
\usetheme[subsectionpage=simple]{metropolis} 
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[OT1,euler-digits]{eulervm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
Text
\begin{align}
E &= \sin(x)\\
\dot{y}
\end{align}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found an answer using this question [Eulervm and LuaLaTeX results in wrong front for math operators](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573024/eulervm-and-lualatex-results-in-wrong-front-for-math-operators). This is not very elegant, but it does work for Windows fonts as well (I'm using Corbel here).

My solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,t]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usetheme{default}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setsansfont{Corbel}

% this simply redefines all the accents and keeps the operators in Corbel font
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{accents}{OT1}{eur}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathAccent{\acute}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"13}
\DeclareMathAccent{\grave}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"12}
\DeclareMathAccent{\ddot}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"7F}
\DeclareMathAccent{\tilde}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"7E}
\DeclareMathAccent{\bar}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"16}
\DeclareMathAccent{\breve}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"15}
\DeclareMathAccent{\check}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"14}
\DeclareMathAccent{\hat}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"5E}
\DeclareMathAccent{\dot}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"5F}
\DeclareMathAccent{\mathring}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"17}

\DeclareMathOperator{\foo}{foo}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
  1+ \hat{\sin} \hat{x} \tilde{x} \foo \quad \text{sin}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Hope this helps either you or the next person who wants to use both eulervm and luatex (and maybe even Windows fonts).

Answer (score 2):

Compiling your example on a TeXLive (linux), I get Fira Sans (Light weight) fonts for text and indeed CM (serif) fonts for maths.

You can choose the matching Fira maths fonts (sans serif only available in Regular weight ) rather than 8-bits fonts by adding

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Fira Sans} % for math operators
\setsansfont{Fira Sans} % for text (instead of the light version)
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
```

Output:
[image]
or if you prefer Euler fonts (no math italics), you could try

```
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Fira Sans Light}[Scale=0.88] % for math operators
\setmathfont{euler.otf}
```

Output:
[image]
The latter (euler.otf) is not included in TeXLive, it is available [github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf) but the project looks like abandoned, sigh…