# Eulervm and LuaLaTeX results in wrong front for math operators

Tags: math-mode, fonts, luatex, fontspec, eulervm

I noticed that the math operators have the wrong font if LuaLaTeX is used.

[image]

If I apply the [fix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272495/54364) from @egreg the accents are wrong:

[image]

The MWE is the following:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[euler-digits,small,OT1]{eulervm}

% fix the font used for operators and \mathrm
\usepackage{fontspec}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \sin \hat{x} \tilde{x} \quad \text{sin}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use legacy fonts for the operators:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[euler-digits,small,OT1]{eulervm}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{EBGaramond-TLF}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
1+ \sin \hat{x} \tilde{x} \quad \text{sin}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use the legacy font only for the accents.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[euler-digits,small,OT1]{eulervm}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{accents}{OT1}{EBGaramond-TLF}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathAccent{\acute}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"13}
\DeclareMathAccent{\grave}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"12}
\DeclareMathAccent{\ddot}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"7F}
\DeclareMathAccent{\tilde}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"7E}
\DeclareMathAccent{\bar}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"16}
\DeclareMathAccent{\breve}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"15}
\DeclareMathAccent{\check}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"14}
\DeclareMathAccent{\hat}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"5E}
\DeclareMathAccent{\dot}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"5F}
\DeclareMathAccent{\mathring}{\mathalpha}{accents}{"17}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
1+ \sin \hat{x} \tilde{x} \quad \text{sin}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx. I own you a drink if we ever meet. You already helped me a dozen times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Neo Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf) in `unicode-math`.